# Why is Apache Mahout's Recommender.recommend() function slow?

Tags: machine-learning, mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I am using Apache Mahout Item Based Recommender with item-item similarity on a data-set of 400 items and 5M users.I am using `TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity` and `GenricItemBasedRecommender`.

But when i call the function recommender.recommend, for every user it takes around 1500 milliseconds to generate a recommendation of 5 items. I have also tried caching in both similarity and and recommendation, but nothing helps. Is there a performance issue with apache mahout 0.8, that it takes so long to generate a recommendation?

Please suggest ways to optimize.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `CandidateItemsStrategy`, and `MostSimilarItemsCandidateItemsStrategy`.
E.g.:

```
CandidateItemsStrategy candidateStrategy = new SamplingCandidateItemsStrategy(...);
MostSimilarItemsCandidateItemsStrategy mostSimilarStrategy = new SamplingCandidateItemsStrategy(...);

Recommender recommender = new GenericItemRecommender(model, similarity, candidateStrategy, mostSimilarStrategy);
```

You can try playing around the with the parameters for sampling candidate items. These are similar to using neighboring users in `UserBasedSimilarity`.

If its still slow, you should consider precomputing all similarities between the items periodically and used them in main memory. You could even try a database calls for the precomputed similarities if you don't have enough main memory.